# Reaching out to employer about different positions

Tags: internship, technology, computer-science

I recently finished an internship and went back to college. Before the internship I thought the position I applied for is what I wanted to do after graduation. However during the internship I found a new interest but I was never able to tell my manager. I thought it didn't make sense that I applied but before leaving completely changed my mind of what I wanted to do. I'd still like to keep in touch with the company and the people I met because they offer an internship and may have openings for my new interest. Is this still professional to reach out? I just think it's odd because a piece of career advice that I got is it doesn't make sense for someone to do an internship in one thing then get a completely different job in another. My major is IST and I wanted to do front end web dev but now I want to get into UI/UX. I feel like I'm side tracking which I know is fine but how does one deal with this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> a piece of career advice that I got is it doesn't make sense for someone to do an internship in one thing then get a completely different job in another.

I'd fundamentally disagree with this. You did the internship, you discovered it wasn't what you wanted to do so you're taking up something you do want to do - nobody sane thinks you should stay in a field which doesn't interest you. *This is one of the things an internship is for*.

So yes, it is entirely professional to contact your internship employer about a different role - they know you and (hopefully) think you are a good person, so even if you're applying for a different role you'll still have one advantage over other candidates. Just be prepared to answer the questions as to why you no longer want to do front end development.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I plan on writing an email to the employer updating them once I finish my last semester. How would you suggest I go about writing the email? I'm not sure how to phrase it.

Comment: Just say what you've said here: you like the company, but you've realised your interests are different from what you interned as.